# How does tumblr point to your domain?

Tags: ip-address, domain, webserver, tumblr, cname

Lets assume I have a tumblr account:

http://sheehan.tumblr.com

Tumblr allows it so that it can point to www.sheehan.com if I enter an A-Record.

How does Tumblr scale this to millions of users? How is it possible to assign a single A-Record to multiple subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically there is an apache/whatever header directive that redirects it to your site. It will be a very small amount of data ( check out 301/ moved permanently headers for more ).

For scaling it to millions, this kind of data ( username (key) -> custom domain(value) ) you could store the data for all the users in a memory mapped hash and then put a squid ( or similar ) proxy to cache.

Comment: I think it's actually key=domain, value=user -- seems like a lot more effective to me.

Comment: from username i mean "sheehan.tumblr.com" and by domain i mean "sheehan.com"